# How to rotate an image .onclick

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, rotation

I am having difficulty getting my image to rotate when I click on it.

I've attached a link to fiddle with my HTML, CSS and JS

http://jsfiddle.net/5x9tgo07/32/

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
  <header>
    <h1 id='heading'>SELF</h1>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <body>
    <div class='introCard'>
      <img id='self' src="https://image.ibb.co/djffuz/self_eye_centered.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
}

.introCard {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center
}

div img {
  width: 35%;
}

hr {
  width: 50%
}
```

Here is my JS

```
let imageToSpin = document.getElementById('self');

function spinImage() {
    imageToSpin.rotate(20 * Math.PI/180);
}

imageToSpin.onclick = spinImage;
```

Comment: Open your browser `console` and you will notice a error telling you why this isn't functioning as intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that questions not showing any search effort are likely to be closed/downvoted. `rotate()` is not a function. You can try to use CSS instead. [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) might help.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you for the console direction. I was curious about how to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

`rotate` is not a method of the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object.

A proper way to rotate the image would be adding (or toggling) a CSS class and rotate it using a [`rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate).

Using your example:

**JS File**

```
let imageToSpin = document.getElementById('self');
imageToSpin.onclick = function () {
  imageToSpin.classList.toggle('rotated')
};
```

**CSS File**

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

And of course the image with `self` id in the HTML somewhere.

[Here is your JSFiddle updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9tgo07/40/)

If you need to calculate the `deg` in JS, then you can set the CSS property by hand in the `onclick` function directly.

Answer (score 0):

create a closure around the stuff you want to use, and then use the `style.transform` like so:

```
let imageToSpin = document.getElementById('self');

function spinImage(imageToSpin) {
  var count = 0
  return function() {
    count += 10;
    imageToSpin.style.transform = `rotate(${count}deg)`;
  }
}

imageToSpin.onclick = spinImage(imageToSpin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could set it up in a quick and short way:

```
  var rotate_angle = 0;

  <img src='blue_down_arrow.png' onclick='rotate_angle = (rotate_angle + 180) % 360; $(this).rotate(rotate_angle);' /></a>
```